# cURL Laravel and Aspx End Point

Tags: php, laravel, curl

Created an PHP LARAVEL API that would use aspx end point to post values. When I post the values I get a 
`FORM ERROR : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String`
From the end point.

I tested my post field values and when I add values using the end point and browser I get a response from the end point but when I use cURL in my controller I get the FORM ERROR

My API Controller

```
          if(!empty($postFields)){                  
              $fields_string = "";

            foreach($postFields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }

                $fields = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

                $this_ch = curl_init();
                $headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
                $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example/test.aspx");
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
       curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
       //curl_setopt($this_ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);

       $result = curl_exec($this_ch);

       echo curl_error($this_ch);
       $info = curl_getinfo($this_ch);
       //var_dump($info);
       curl_close($this_ch);
       return $result;

            }
```

Comment: Did you have debugged your POST Request and can show us the result?

Comment: "FORM ERROR : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String" thats the error am getting

Comment: I mean your POST Request. Something like ... parameter=value&parameter=value